# Let $f$ be uniformly continuous ,$f(0)=0$ show $\exists M>0$ st $|f(x)|\le 1+M|x|$

Tags: uniform-continuity

> Consider a uniformly continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=0$, Prove that there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le 1+M|x|$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: After 8 months on the site and 15 questions asked, you cannot neglect to add anything personal like that.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311734/uniformly-continuous-function-acts-almost-like-an-lipschitz-function) may help.

Comment: @Did sorry didn't get what you mean to say !

Comment: Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. That way, we know exactly what help you need.

Comment: @Did thanks surely i'll take care of that from next time

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon=1$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon=1$. Let $M=\frac1 \delta$.

Now if $x>0$ let $n$ be minimal with $n\delta>x$. Let $x_k=\frac {kx}{n}$, for $0\le k\le n$. Then $x_0=0$, $x_n=n$ and $x_{k+1}-x_k=\frac x{n}<\delta$, hence $|f(x_{ĸ+1})-f(x_k)|<1$ and finally $|f(x_n)-f(x_0)|<n$, i.e. $|f(x)|<n$. Since $(n-1)\delta\le x$, we see that $|f(x)|<\frac x\delta+1=1+M|x|$.

The case $x<0$ follows similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous.  That is: for any $\epsilon>0:$ for any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, there is a $\delta_\epsilon$ such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta_\epsilon \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon
$$
Setting $\epsilon=1$, there is a $\delta_1$ such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<1
$$
Thus, selecting some $\Delta x<\delta_1$, we have 
$$
\left|f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\right|<1
$$
Or, perhaps more intuitively,
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}\right|<\frac{1}{\Delta x}
$$
That is, over any interval of length $\Delta x$, $f$ has a maximum average rate of change of $\frac{1}{\Delta x}$.

Now, I claim that setting $M=\frac1{\Delta x}$ meets the requirements of this theorem, by the following proof:

Consider any $x_0\in\mathbb R$.  Let $n=\lfloor x_0/\Delta x \rfloor$, $\Delta x_0= x_0-n\Delta x$, and $M=\frac1{\Delta x}$.  Then we have (in the general case that $n>2$)
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0)&=f(n\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&<1+f((n-1)\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&<2+f((n-2)\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&<\cdots\\
&<n+f(0+\Delta x_0)\\
&<n+1 = 1+ \lfloor x_0/\Delta x \rfloor\\
&< 1 + x_0/\Delta x = 1 + Mx_0
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\begin{align}
f(x_0)&=f(n\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&>-1+f((n-1)\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&>-2+f((n-2)\Delta x+\Delta x_0)\\
&>\cdots\\
&>-n+f(0+\Delta x_0)\\
&>-n-1 = -\left(1+ \lfloor x_0/\Delta x \rfloor\right)\\
&> \left(1 + x_0/\Delta x\right) = -\left(1 + Mx_0\right)
\end{align}
$$
The statement follows.

Comment: Honestly? No idea.

Comment: @Did I suppose my hint didn't have the intended effect, then. My intention was to make an appeal to geometric intuition by bringing up the average slope over an interval. I'll try to make this clearer.